# MYSQL join two tables and list oldest entry

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with data I would like to select.
Basically it is a Helpdesk system and it collects information about ticket activity.

```
Table #1

ticket_id   log_type        entry_date 

   1       ticket_created   1471442825
   1       ticket_closed    1471442825
   2       ticket_created   1438035457
   2       ticket_closed    1438035269
   3       ticket_created   1438034956
   3       ticket_closed    1438034121



Table #2

ticket_id   customer_name   status

   1          Bill          open
   2          John          closed
   3          Mark          canncelled
```

What I would like to get is

```
ticket_id   customer_name     log_type      entry_date

   1           Bill         ticket_created  1471442825
   2           John         ticket_created  1471442825
   3           Mark         ticket_created  1471442825
```

where the oldest entry_date would be 5 days or more (to list outdated tickets).

I have tried several joins but I didn’t succeed.

Comment: You want only tickets that are still open?

Comment: I don't understand how the result set relates to the data set

Comment: Corect I wan't the tickets that are still open

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` with `MIN(entry_date)`, e.g.:

```
SELECT t2.ticket_id, t2.customer_name, t1.log_type, t1.date
FROM table_2 t2,
JOIN (SELECT ticket_id, MIN(entry_date) AS `date`
FROM table_1
GROUP BY ticket_id) t1
ON t2.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id AND t2.entry_date = t1.date;
```

To filter out the records, you can add another condition on `t1.date` with `DATE_ADD` function.